# Calculate probability that team A scores against team B

Tags: probability

I'm trying to calculate the probability of an event for my math classes but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correct.

As I'm a sports fan I'm using a football match as subject.

In the last $3$ matches team A score on average $1.33$ goals per match.
Team B conceded $0.67$ goals per match.

What are the chances that Team A scores against Team B?

I did $(1.33 \cdot 0.67)/2 = 44\%$.
Is this correct?

Comment: Notice that the rates are not necessarily comparable. Are the teams even playing in the same league? If the other team is the best team in the world, and the other is a bunch of 5-year-old kids ...

Comment: Your method cannot be correct.  To see this, suppose team A scores an average of $3$ goals per match, while team B concedes an average of $1$ goal per match.  Then you method yields $\frac{3 \cdot 1}{2} = 1.5 > 1$, which violates the requirement that a probability be between $0$ and $1$ inclusive.

Comment: @MattiP. What if the two teams are equal in strenght?

Comment: @Sonia What would you think is the consequence? If they indeed are equal in strength, perhaps the chance is $50~\%$, regardless of their previous matches. Anyway, I would answer this question like so: "The probability cannot be realistically modeled with the given data". See NF Taussig's comment for reasoning for this.

Comment: I suspect that the given data is insufficient for solving the problem. Still, maybe we can calculate the estimated number of goals team A scores against B, by taking their arithmetic mean. Then we could use the normal distribution to estimate the probability mass for (>0.5) goals. Not sure how meaningful that is tho, in terms of the desired answer for this domain. You mention that this is for a math class. It would help if you could provide some context for this. A reference to a book where this is mentioned or topics taught to you around this might help someone hit on a answer.

Comment: I've answered this question on the assumption that for your math class, you've been asked to come up with a scenario with a probability set-up, and then to solve for some probability within that set-up.  Is that so?

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in some comments, your data does not contain sufficient information to answer this question. Assume that team A shoots 3 goals in a match with probability 1. So the mean is 3 goals per match. Team B shoots 1 goal with p=1/3, 4 goals with p=2/3, then the mean is 3, too. Team C shoots 0 goals with p=2/3 and 9 goals with p=1/3, then again the mean is 3. But A will win 2 games out of three when playing against C, and only 1 out of three when playint against B.

Answer (score 0):

There are methods to compute such parameters as expected scoring or probability of scoring at least one goal, but these are empirical and heuristic (that is, a rule of thumb based on statistical surveys of games), and probably would not apply the principles of probability that you've learned in your class.  Only you would be able to say for sure, though.

In all likelihood, if you want to apply these principles to sports, you will have to do it with a fairly simplified version of those games.  For instance, winners of best two of three.  Suppose A beats B in any given match with probability $p = 3/5$ (independent of any past results).  What is the probability that A wins a best-two-of-three series against B?  What if $p$ were some other value?  What if it were best three of five?

Hope this helps.